# is it necessary to call pthread_mutex_destroy both in parent and child process

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, synchronous

here is the code:

```
struct mt {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_mutexattr_t mutexattr;
};

int main(void) {
    struct mt *mm;
    pid_t pid;

    int fd = open("my_name", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777);
    ftruncate(fd, sizeof(*mm));
    mm = (struct mt *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(*mm), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    close(fd);
    unlink("my_name");

    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mm->mutexattr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mm->mutexattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mm->mutex, &mm->mutexattr);


    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mm->mutex);
        doSomething();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mm->mutex);
    } else {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mm->mutex);
        doSomething();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mm->mutex);
        wait(NULL);

    }
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mm->mutexattr);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mm->mutex);

    return 0;
}
```

The child process is forked by parent process. And mutex is shared between parent and child process. At the end of routine, pthread_mutex_destroy is called totally two times by parent and child process. Is it necessary to call pthread_mutex_destroy both in parent process and child process?

Comment: It's not shared. It's duplicated in the new process.

Comment: The mutex is shared between processes as long as the implementation supports process-shared mutexes (check the return value) and the memory containing the mutex is shared (which it is in this case). Since there is only one mutex object shared by both processes, only one process can destroy it. Destroying an already destroyed mutex results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @stark It's alllocated in shared memory.

Comment: @IanAbbott `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` [doesn't seem to be optional under POSIX 7](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.html).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, it looks like it. The discontinued Glibc port for Google Native Client (NaCl) did not support `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` though. The Linux man page probably hasn't been updated to make `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` support non-optional.

Answer (score 0):

Per [POSIX 7's `pthread_mutex_destroy()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `pthread_mutex_destroy()` function shall destroy the mutex object
> referenced by `mutex`; the mutex object becomes, in effect,
> uninitialized.  ...
>
> ...
>
> The behavior is undefined if the value specified by the `mutex`
> argument to `pthread_mutex_destroy()` does not refer to an initialized
> mutex.

Given "the mutex object becomes, in effect, uninitialized" when it's destroyed the first time, a second call to `pthread_mutex_destroy()` - even from another process - will invoke undefined behavior because "the `mutex` argument to `pthread_mutex_destroy()` does not refer to an initialized mutex".

Thus only one process can safely destroy the mutex.